# Three.js create different ids for different vertex/fragmentShaders?

Tags: three.js, webgl

So I noticed that shaders must be declared in the html document and not inside an external js file. Also the different shaders must have different ids associated with them. My question is, when creating multiple shaders do I have to create multiple script tags and give each of those different ids or do all my
shaders of a type go inside one script tag?

```
<script id="vertexShader1" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
void main() {}
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader1" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
void main() {}
</script>


<script id="vertexShader2" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
void main() {}
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader2" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
void main() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

WebGL does not care where your shader source code comes from. There is absolutely nothing stopping you from loading them via AJAX, streaming them in via WebSockets, or somehow hiding them deep within a super special PNG image.

It is just often convenient to store shaders within the HTML source so that they can easily be referenced on page load.

The raw underlying WebGL methods simply take a string as the shader's source code, so there isn't anything forcing you to specifically use script tags.

Comment: So I dont need: x-shader/x-vertex?

Comment: I mean assuming I load it in an external script file how do I specify if it is a vertex or fragment shader code?

Comment: no you don't need "x-shader/x-vertex" you just need something that's not "javascript" otherwise the browser will try to execute the code.